# How to receive POST response from another application through browser

Tags: angular

Error:

> Cannot POST /responsehandler

In app-routing.module.ts configured like below

```
{path:'responsehandler',component:ResponsehandlerComponent},
```

My doubt is how to get the post response body (data) in Angular through the browser.

Actually from Angular, I did redirect to another URL (another project), They validating the request and show some information in the browser, at last, they redirect to my angular using a browser, they sent in a post (method type) and data in the body through browser redirection.

```
   <form action="http://localhost:4200/responsehandler" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Some"><br><br>
      <input type="text" id="age" name="age" value="11"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the routes you configure in the routing module is for page navigation via routes only, Angular is not an api for server interaction.
you can call an api in angular to get response from a server.

Comment: Thanks for your response, That means I will depend on some other APIs? apart from redirection, I will use angular services on this requirement.